# How to acces dictionary variable from ansible jinja2 templates?

Tags: json, jinja2, ansible, devops

i want to access the size_available variable from Dict list

```
"ansible_mounts": [
    {
        "device": "/dev/sda1",
        "fstype": "ext4",
        "mount": "/",
        "options": "rw,errors=remount-ro",
        "size_available": 15032406016,
        "size_total": 20079898624
    }
]

- action: debug msg="mem= {{ ansible_mounts.size_available }}"
```

TASK [debug] *******************************************************************

```
fatal: [127.0.0.1]: FAILED! => {"failed": true, "msg": "'list' object has no attribute 'size_available'"}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you please check this, didn't test it:

```
- action: debug msg="mem= {{ ansible_mounts[0].size_available }}"
```

Comment: yep. TLDR, not a dict, it's a list and dict.

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to do the same thing, turned out to be way more complicated than I expected!

```
{{ (ansible_mounts|selectattr("mount","equalto","/tmp")|list)[0].size_available }}
```